# Quotes in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The variable `@it_codigo` is used to get a ntext value from other table in a procedure and is used for a select like:

```
SELECT * FROM anaProdutos WHERE cod_produto LIKE @it_codigo
```

But this doesn't work, missing quotes. I tried

```
''+@it_codigo+''
```

and

```
QUOTENAMES(@it_codigo, '')
```

But that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using LIKE you'd want something as per below;

```
LIKE '%' + @it_codigo + '%'
```

You need the percentage signs for the LIKE to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WHERE cod_produto LIKE '%' + @it_codigo + '%'
```

Check [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-like-clause.htm) for more information on `LIKE` keyword.